# Is Realm a Object Graph Manager along with its own implementation for a DBMS?

Tags: ios, database, core-data, realm, object-graph

**CoreData** is an **Object Graph Manager** which can work with different store types, with SQLite being the most popular one as it is persistent. It provides **graphs of 'NSManagedObject'**.

***Is Realm also an Object Graph Manager as it provides graphs of 'Object'***, with its own implementation of a database management store? If **Object Graph Manager** and **DBMS** are **two different things** why *Realm claims to be a DBMS instead of claiming to be a both*?

*Also in general if your own **custom designed database interface***(a custom solution as an option to CoreData and Realm that you might implement) ***provides objects linking to underlying records*** in the custom store implementation(Some object Similar to NSManagedObject for CoreData and Object for Realm) isnt it a **Object Graph Manager** with a underlying store *or* is it a **DBMS**?

Comment: The question is unclear; where are you seeing Realm advertised as an 'Object Graph Manager'? While Realm can provide a view of objects at a particular place in time, I am not sure what comparison is being made. CD is formally an object graph backed by a variety of different stores, Realm is realm. Generally, if you want to create an API that can be backed by .plist and .txt files then yes, it would be a Manger, not the actual db. It's a good idea on SO to keep questions limited to one topic; in depth, discussion questions are OT. It's best to stick to specific coding questions and issues.

Comment: I just want to know is Realm a Object Graph Manager along with being a DBMS or just a plain DBMS. Realm provides linked Objects which are graphs corresponding to  records.

Comment: Where are you seeing *linked Objects which are graphs corresponding to records*? Realm not an Object Graph Manager like Core Data. Realm manages it's own objects and database and is a unified DBMS product, unlike CD which is a manager that can be backed by a variety of stores. Again though what's the use case? Why are you asking? It's hard to answer when you're making statements but not providing the source or the context of those statements.

Comment: In Realm arent Object subclasses related to other Object subclasses? And arent Object instances a record stored in Realm

Comment: *In Realm arent Object subclasses related to other Object subclasses*. That's vague because it depends on what objects we are talking about and what is considered a 'relation' in this use case. You're really asking about [Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) in general. Subclasses are related to their parent class and each other. They are not *related* to a different parents subclasses. Realm objects exist in code and the backing data exists in a Realm File. Again though, this is off topic for SO because it's not a specific coding question.

Comment: Sorry if you it is a generic question. Could you suggest where can I post or move it then?

Comment: I really can't because what you're asking is unclear so I wouldn't know where to send you. It doesn't seem to be really about Realm - it seems more that you need clarification on object oriented programming. I asked several times where you're getting your information from without response - perhaps that source would be a good place to start if you have questions about their statetments

Comment: I am not talking about OOP here. I meant as NSManagedObjects can be linked and thus form an ObjectGraph, so do Realm's Obects and form an ObjectGraph.

Comment: Again, what's being asked it unclear. Lot's of (OOP) database systems employ object graphs and offer relationships between the objects which form those graphs - it's kinda common in today's world. Core Data is backed by a variety of stores; Realm is **not** backed by a variety of stores. Do you have a specific coding question? If so, please provide the code you're asking about and clarify the question.

Comment: Core Data is Object Graph Manager as it does that specifically, backed by different types of stores. Realm also implements its own store i.e database system to be specific and on the application side tops it up with its flavour of Object Graph Manager. Is that sentence correct?

Comment: I would say no because Realm does not have an 'Object Graph Manager'. A graph could be considered a visual representations of the links and relationships between objects. Core Data has that - open Xcode and your Core Data project and you can see an actual 'Graph' of all of you objects. Realm offers nothing like that and any relationships and links can only be derived by inspecting the actual code; there is no graph. Again though, without understanding the context, it's unclear what you're asking. You should contact Realm Sales if you have further questions.